# Prove that $x_1+2x_2+3x_3+\cdots+nx_n \leq \frac{n(n-1)}{2}+x_1+x_2^2+x_3^3+\cdots+x_n^n$ where $x_i > 0$ for all $i$ from $1$ to $n$ inclusive.

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, contest-math

**Question:**

Prove that $x_1+2x_2+3x_3+\cdots+nx_n \leq \frac{n(n-1)}{2}+x_1+x_2^2+x_3^3+\cdots+x_n^n$ where $x_i > 0$ for all $i$ from $1$ to $n$ inclusive.

---

This is a nice problem from the polish math olympiad (I'm not from poland but still good practice) and I solved it in a very gross way (bashing) and want to see an AM-GM proof since I know I've been told its possible.

Comment: I explicitly asked for a proof by saying "Prove that...". Also, I had further edits in the P.S section but my question has been edited. Why should my reputation take such a hit because of someone else editting my question? I'm going back to AoPs forums, this is incredible...

Comment: I didn't know I could roll-back something. Anyways this is just a nice problem from the polish math olympiad (I'm not from poland but still good practice) and I solved it in a very gross way (bashing) and want to see an AM-GM proof since I know I've been told its possible

Comment: I just bashed it there is no merit to that. I will not answer any further questions here since this has remained a downvote even though I provided context and honestly I'm quite fed up with this site.

Comment: I've added your previous comment in your question.

Comment: You need to show some of your work (even if incomplete) to get help at this site - just saying "I bashed it" won't cut it. In any case, as you seem a new user, here's a hint using AM-GM: $x^k+(k-1)\geqslant kx$ (why?)

Comment: I notice $x^n-nx+n-1 \geq 0$ when $x>0$. Proving that would be a fairly nice way to do it. Doesn't really use AM-GM though.

Comment: @aschepler Split the $k-1$ into a bunch of $1$s.  Then it's a direct application of AM-GM of all terms in LHS.

Answer (score 3):

Note that using AM-GM:
$$
x_k = x_k \prod_{i=1}^{k-1}1 \leq \frac{k-1 + x_k^k}{k}\implies kx_k\leq k-1 + x_k^k
$$
for $k \geq 1$. Now sum each inequality along $k$ and you get the desired inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Lemma: For $x>0$ and $i=1,2,\dots$,
$$x^i+i \geqslant ix+1$$
Proof of lemma:

If $x \leqslant 1$  then
$$1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^{i-1} \leqslant 1+1+1+\cdots + 1 = i$$
$$\frac{1-x^i}{1-x} \leqslant i$$
$$1-x^i\leqslant i-ix$$
$$x^i+i \geqslant ix+1$$

On the other hand, if $x>1$ then, by the binomial theorem,
$$x^i=(1+(x-1))^i=1+i(x-1)+\cdots$$
where all of the terms are positive, so
$$x^i \geqslant 1+i(x-1)$$
$$x^i+i \geqslant ix+1$$

We now set $x=x_i$ in the lemma and sum, to get
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i^i+i) \geqslant \sum_{i=1}^n  (ix_i+1)$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^i + \frac{n(n-1)}2 \geqslant \sum_{i=1}^n  ix_i$$

as required.